# how to access UCWA API in android code?

Tags: ucwa

I want to access UCWA API in android code. Is it possible?.

If possible, pls give me an idea and hello world program.

does UCWA API support for Video Chat and Screen Sharing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UCWA is a REST based API, so there's no reason why you wouldn't be able to access it from an Android app. Your best bet is to look through the samples on http://ucwa.lync.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are no known Java libraries available, so you have to do all of that on your own. Paul's link is a good place to start, however you might also find the MS pages on a C# implementation useful(1), they certainly are cleaner than the Javascript based samples at http://ucwa.lync.com/
As for supporting video chat and screen sharing, the answer for now seems to be no. UCWA may be able to initiate these on the users Lync client though.

(1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn551186%28v=office.15%29.aspx